# send email by using codeigniter library via server

Tags: codeigniter, server, smtp

i want to send email using SMTP protocol Via server.my server is host gator.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdKPe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks... i done it with same code...

just change the port then its working....

here is code

function do_email($msg=NULL, $sub=NULL, $to=NULL, $from=NULL){
        $this->load->library('email');

```
    $config = array();
    $config['protocol']='smtp';
    $config['smtp_host']='localhost';
    $config['smtp_port']='587';
    $config['charset']='utf-8';
    $config['newline']="\r\n";
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';

    $this->email->initialize($config);


    $this->email->from($from, $system_name);
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->subject($sub);
    $this->email->message($msg);
    $email = $this->email->send();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need configure user and pass in configs

specify your problem better